# Can I assign the left side of a stereo channel to both subgroups in a stereo set and assign it stereo in a different set?

Tags: mixer

I have a Behringer x2442usb mixer which has a stereo effects unit.  I would like to be able to assign the effect to both sub-groups 1-2 and 3-4, with subgroup 1-2 for left channel only while subgroup 3-4 would be a stereo pair. Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this with most sound boards and your mixer is no exception (and is actually even more limited).

Individual sub-group channels are mono, not stereo, you can only choose to assign sub-groups to left, right, both or neither, but the same thing goes to anything you assign them to.  When working as a stereo pair, you make odd number sub-groups left channel and even numbers right.  You can use the pan of a channel to decide how much of the signal goes to each of the two subgroups, but the same balance goes to every pair of sub-groups that you assign the channel to.  There is generally no option for separate balancing per sub-group.

Even further for your board, effect routing can either be to the mains or one set of sub-groups.  Either 1-2 or 3-4.  There does not appear to be an option to send it to both.  This should really be done as a stereo pair (one assigned left, one assigned right) since effects sometimes make use of stereo space.  If you are outputting to mono then it doesn't matter so much though.